# Spring-security - invalid login always return 403 instead of appropriate errors

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to input some more "accurate" error handling for invalid logins.

The three main objectives: invalid password, account disabled, invalid email.

The current calling hierarchy is the following:

Attempted login requests

```
    @Override // THIS OVERRIDES THE DEFAULT SPRING SECURITY IMPLEMENTATION
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, password);
        return authManager.authenticate(authToken);
    }
```

This calls another override method where I tried to insert error handling because it has access to the userRepo and object. The issue here is if the `AccountLockedException` or fails on email finding or password verification, it will always reutrn a 403 and no indication of the thrown exception.

```
    @SneakyThrows
    @Override // THIS OVERWRITES THE DEFAULT SPRING SECURITY ONE
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email){
        User user = findUserByEmail(email);
        if ( user != null){
            if (user.isEnabled()){
                Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
                user.getRoles().forEach(role -> { authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));});
                sucessfulLogin(user);
                return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
            }
            else { throw new AccountLockedException("Account disabled"); }
        }
    }
```

However, what I have found this previous method on throwing will call this additional override method (in the same class as the attempted authentication)

```
    @Override // DO SOMETHING WITH THIS TO PREVENT BRUTE FORCE ATTACKS WITH LIMITED NUMBER OF ATTEMPTS IN A TIME-FRAME
    protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("aaa");
        super.unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed);
    }
```

Though, at this point it will display the following:

1. this option gets shown when the password is incorrect.
   [image]
2. this option gets shown when the account is disabeld.
   [image]
3. this option gets shown when the email is incorrect.
   [image]

My question is. Firstly how do I appropriately distinguish between these errors and secondly send appropriate http responses based on these errors?

Comment: You shouldn't as those messages are a security risk (it tells a hacker if something is a valid or invalud account, etc. so it exposes information you don't want to expose). Also the account disable check is already done by Spring Security.

Comment: @M.Deinum that's why you can also see I left myself a code comment to prevent brute-force. I doubt somebody will spend their time sending 3 requests per hour. Also the account disable in my case is not done by spring security because im using a custom user class

Comment: With a bot network that won't help, anyway you want to keep those messages as generic as possible. For your check, you already return the Spring Security user which you simply can pass the enabled flag and it will be taken into consideration. As your current `UserDetailsService` breaks the contract of the interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        if (failed != null) {

            if (failed.getMessage() == "AccountLockedException") {
                response.setStatus(403);
            } // if account is disabled
            else if (failed.getMessage() == "EntityNotFoundException") {
                response.setStatus(400);
            } // if email incorrect
            else if (failed.getMessage() == "Bad credentials") {
                response.setStatus(400);
            } // if password incorrect
            else {
                System.out.println("some kind of other authentication error");
                response.setStatus(418); // some random error incase this ever happens
            }
```